# how to fix typescript eslint error: Parsing error: Type expected

Tags: typescript, eslint

typescript support string literal union type from enum,but eslint with error,how to fix??

```
enum Kind {
  'info' = 'info',
  'positive' = 'positive',
  'negative' = 'negative',
  'warning' = 'warning',
}
export type KindType = `${Kind}`;
```

eslint error in `export type KindType = ${Kind};`

```
{
    "owner": "eslint",
    "message": "Parsing error: Type expected.",
    "source": "eslint"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So you can directly export the enum from the file. This approach can be helpful

```
export enum Kind {
  'info' = 'info',
  'positive' = 'positive',
  'negative' = 'negative',
  'warning' = 'warning',
}
```

Now you can import it in your other files, And use them accordingly.

```
import {Kind} from "./main"

Kind.info
```

Happy coding.